# How to get the SUM() of a specific value from another column in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to get the Sum() or total completed status  of a specific user per day,per user & per transaction.

Sample data :
MyTable

```
| user    |   status  |  (columnName)    
| ------  |  -------- |   
| user1   | completed |   
| user1   | completed |  
| user2   | pending   |
```

The expected result should be :

```
| User  | Status   |total(Completed)|   
| ----- | ------   |----------------|   
| USER1 |COMPLETED |    2           |
```

It should only display the sum of completed status .

I tried some syntax here but it seems too complex and it's not giving me the expected result.I'm just a begginer in sql and a simple syntax for this problem would be helpful.

Also im having difficulty aligning the tables here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation, and show status as "COMPLETED" directly, given that you want only counts for completed status values.

```
SELECT user,
       'COMPLETED' AS status, 
       COUNTIF(status='completed') AS total_completed
FROM tab
GROUP BY user
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try with this one.

```
SELECT user, status, count(*) as total 
FROM MyTable
WHERE status ='completed' 
GROUP BY user, status
```

P.S
I would go with integer column in MyTable and reference that column with MyTableStatus table so you can have string explanation of the statuses if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you inly need to re ove qall rpws without COMPLETED and count them

```
SELECT
user, status, COUNT(*) as total
 FROM MyTable
WHERE status = 'COMPLETED'
GROUP BY user,status
```

Comment: Hi I just wanna clarify I still want to display the other status but their total would be zero and completed will have the total value only

Comment: TT here removes all other status, when you remove it you get all the count as rows , to get columns y ou need to pivot them